# Why do I get an error when iterating over paragraphs in MS Word with win32com?

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

It is giving the following error

```
print Text  
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encodereturn codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map) 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position  0: 
character maps to undefined
```

The code i am using is

```
import win32com.client
import os
MSWord = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
MSWord.Visible = True
Document = MSWord.Documents.Open(os.getcwd()+'\\' + 'MARS.doc')
for paragraph in Document.Paragraphs:
    Text = paragraph.Range.Text  
    print Text
```

Comment: While many of us would be happy to help answer your question, we are much more likely to understand the problem and provide a helpful answer if you show us the code you've already tried. Here's some info on how to provide [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: When you [edit] your question, select the code portions and press the `{ }` button. That indents it properly to be displayed. Look at the preview below the edit window to see how your code will look

Comment: @mhlester +1 for coaching, I did the edits for them this time hopefully that helps too

Answer (score 0):

Your Text has unicode characters that cannot be printed to stdout. Try

```
Document = MSWord.Documents.Open(os.getcwd()+'\\' + 'MARS.doc')
counter = 0
for paragraph in Document.Paragraphs:
    counter += 1
    Text = paragraph.Range.Text  
    print "paragraph to edit:", counter, ":"
    print str(Text).encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

this way the non-printable characters will show up as '?'. But if you clarify in your question what you are really trying to do (probably some text processing), you'll get more useful answers.

Comment: i want to see the paragraphs number so that i can edit at required paras

Comment: please explain "paragraphs number"

Comment: i put a count in paragraph iteration so i can see the position in ms word where i need to edit

Comment: So what is the problem remaining? Print the paragraph counter? I've edited.